# How to solve the SVG flash of unstyled color when using currentColor?

Tags: css, svg

I'm using `currentColor` to set the svg fill value via css. This works without a problem, except during load, where the svg loads as black first, then switches to the correct color once the css loads.

I've tried a number of different approaches, including using inline styles, having two fill declarations hoping for precedence to take effect when currentColor isn't yet defined, etc.

Whenever I have an actual fill color defined, I can't seem to get it to change to whatever the currentColor value is when it loads.

What am I missing?

Comment: At the moment you're missing an [mcve] in the question.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1

Use a `<style>` tag inside the SVG (or before the SVG element in the DOM), then load other CSS after that.

```html
<svg>
  <style>
    .color-1 {
      color: lightblue;
    }
  </style>
  <rect class="color-1" width="100%" height="100%" fill="currentColor"/>
</svg>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

Give the element you want to reference a `class` or an `id`, and use it to overwrite the color later.

```css
/* styles.css */
.color-1 {
  color: aquamarine;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
```

If you're worried about putting CSS inside the `<body>`, you can load the stylesheet in the `<head>` instead and use `!important`, but that might cause other problems down the line.

### Solution 2

Instead of relying on `currentColor` use the `fill` property directly:

```html
<svg>
  <rect class="color-1" width="100%" height="100%" fill="lightblue"/>
</svg>
...
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

```css
/* styles.css */
.color-1 {
  fill: aquamarine;
  transition: fill .2s ease;
}
```

This works because classes and ids have higher specificity than the `fill` property.

Both solutions can be used on the root `<svg>` element if you prefer.